# React is not defined when install one exported component on bit.dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, bit, bit.dev

I have followed the [official tutorial of Bit for React](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/tutorials/bit-react-tutorial). And the result is here: https://bit.dev/vibe/react-admin-components/action-buttons

The problem is, I can not install the above component in another project as a npm package. It says `React is undefined` when run time (not build time) with this import: `import ActionButtons from '@bit/vibe.react-admin-components.components';`

I believe this is a happy case, there is no magic here. Maybe babel is the issue here when I use `React 17` and `babel 7`.

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Josh from the Bit team.
I published a new version of the React compiler that now support React 17, please use the new version and re-export your component.
https://bit.dev/bit/envs/compilers/react?version=1.0.23

Answer (score 1):

The error `React is undefined` means that your default Bit compiler for React isn't configured correctly to support the new JSX transformer.

**Steps to fix**

1. Fork the default [Bit compiler](https://bit.dev/bit/envs/compilers/react) follow this [guideline](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/building-components#forking-a-compiler)
2. Update the forked compiler's `.babelrc` to use automatic runtime follow the section **Configuration** [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-17-new-jsx-transform-c6f983f3464d).
   *Note that you have to upgrade the `@babel/preset-react` dependency of the compiler to >=7.9.0*
3. Rebuild your component using the new compiler
4. Export that component again and enjoy